# For vs Parallel.For Behaviour

Tags: vb.net, parallel.foreach

Can anyone offer an explanation as to the different behaviour between `For..Next` loop and a `Parallel.For..Next` loop? I know that the 2nd parameter in the `Parallel.For` loop is exclusive and that the `For` loop `To` parameter is inclusive, but why is this?

I've been rewriting my code to parallelize it at much as possible, but this behaviour is making it a pain.

Comment: For next is VB specific but parallel .for is .NET general

Comment: So .net behaviour is for an inclusive  start parameter, but an exclusive end parameter? But across most if not all other languages, all loop parameters are inclusive. Counter-intuitive.

Comment: They have nothing in common.  The second parameter has a pretty good name, `toExlusive` leaves little guessing.  So usually 1 less than the `To` value.  The way the `For` keyword works was decided 53 years ago in Darthmouth with a preference for counting from 1.  Parallel.For() was influenced by curly brace language preferences, counting from 0 and using `<` for the loop end condition is very common.  Blindly replacing For with Parallel.For is a pretty bad idea, you never want to risk adding threading race bugs for no benefit.  Use a profiler first.

Comment: I stand corrected - Thanks for the profiler tip